# natural inclusion $ε(R)→E(K)$,$x→x$, regarding Neron model of elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, schemes, arithmetic-geometry

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over field $K$, and $ε$ be an Neron model of $E/K$.
I heard there is natural inclusion
$ε(R)→E(K)$, $x→x$.

I understand $ε(R)＝${$R$-morphisms, Spec$R→ε$}(sections of $R$-scheme $ε$) , $E(K)＝${$K$-morphisms, Spec$K→E$}($K$-rational point), but I cannot understand why the titled map is inclusion.

Could you give me explanation why $S$-morphisms, Spec$R→ε$ is regards as $K$-morphisms, Spec$K→E$ ?

(In the situation $E$ and $ε$ are defined by the same equation・・・①,$ε(R)$ and $E(R)$ corresponds to $R$($K$)-rational point of $E$, so the inclusion is obvious, but in general ① is not supposed)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that $\varepsilon$ is a Neron model of $E/K$. This means that $\varepsilon_K = E$ as schemes over $\operatorname{Spec} K$ (Note that $\varepsilon_K$ is the generic fiber of $\varepsilon \to \operatorname{Spec} R$).

Therefore, by base change, an $R$-valued point of $\varepsilon$ gives a morphism $$\operatorname{Spec} K = (\operatorname{Spec} R)_K \to \varepsilon_K = E,$$

i.e. a $K$-valued point of $E$. This is the map $\varepsilon(R) \to E(K)$.

For the term inclusion to make sense, you would at least want this map to be injective. As a consequence of the Neron mapping property, a $K$-valued point of $E$ is determined by a unique $R$-valued point of $\varepsilon$. In particular, this means that the map $\varepsilon(R) \to E(K)$ is bijective.

To address whether you can view $\varepsilon(R) \to E(K)$ as an inclusion without using the mapping property, note that if $r, s$ are two $R$-valued points of $\varepsilon$ whose base changes to $\operatorname{Spec} K$ are equal, i.e. $r_K = s_K$, then by definition of the base change you can show that the compositions $$
\operatorname{Spec} K \to \operatorname{Spec} R \xrightarrow{r} \varepsilon, \\
\operatorname{Spec} K \to \operatorname{Spec} R \xrightarrow{s} \varepsilon \\
$$ are equal. This is to say, $r$ and $s$ agree on the generic point $\xi$ of $\operatorname{Spec} R$.

Using @Alex's comment, since $\varepsilon$ is a separated scheme over $\operatorname{Spec} R$, the diagonal morphism $\Delta : \varepsilon \to \varepsilon \times_{\operatorname{Spec} R} \varepsilon$ is a closed immersion. Hence the locus of agreement of $r, s$ (the pullback of $\Delta$ along $(r, s) : \operatorname{Spec} R \to \varepsilon \times_{\operatorname{Spec} R} \varepsilon$) is a closed immersion $i : V \to \operatorname{Spec} R$. In particular $ri = si$, so $r$ and $s$ agree on a closed subscheme of $\operatorname{Spec} R$. Since $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is reduced and irreducible and $r$ and $s$ agree on the generic point, they must agree on $\operatorname{Spec} R$ and you have $r = s$.

Comment: I often here (for example, Silverman's 'advanced topics in the arithmetic of elliptic curves'), 'natural inclusion'$ε(R)→E(K)$ is bijective because of Neron mapping property, Is it hard to regard $ε(R)→E(K)$ as inclusion without Neron mapping property ?

Comment: I'm not too sure on the specifics, but if two points $r, s \in \varepsilon(R)$ are equal after base change to $K$, then by definition of the base change you have that $r \varphi = s \varphi$, where $\varphi : \operatorname{Spec} K \to \operatorname{Spec} R$ is the canonical map. In particular that means that $r$ and $s$ agree generically, and since $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is reduced and $\varepsilon$ is separated (since it is a neron model), they are equal. So the morphism $\varepsilon(R) \to E(K)$ is injective.

Comment: I'm not sure if this argument works for any $R$, but it works whenever the generic point of $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is open, for example when $R$ is a discrete valuation ring.

Comment: I suppose that you could argue that for any non-generic point of $\operatorname{Spec} R$, corresponding to a prime $\mathfrak p$, you have (with $f : \operatorname{Spec} R_{\mathfrak p} \to \operatorname{Spec} R$) that $rf$ and $sf$ agree on the generic point, and since $R_{\mathfrak p}$ is a DVR $rf = sf$, thus $r$ and $s$ also agree on the point corresponding to $\mathfrak p$. Thus they agree on all points hence $r = s$.

Comment: @dandelion The injectivity should just follow from the fact that $R$ is a valuation ring, and that $\mathcal{E}\to\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is separated--no?

Comment: If $R$ is a valuation ring then indeed just the observation that $r$ and $s$ agree on the generic point would be enough. I think in general $R$ is assumed to be a Dedekind domain for Neron models, and to be honest I have no idea if Dedekind domains are valuation rings. If they are, I'll gladly update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I mean if you don't want to use the valuative criterion, then you can just note that for two morphisms $f,g\colon\mathrm{Spec}(R)\to \mathcal{E}$ over $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$, since $\mathcal{E}$ is separated over $S$ we know that the locus where they agree is closed. Since it contains the generic point, it's topologically the full space, but since $R$ is reduced it must be the entire scheme, so they're equal.

Comment: Thanks, that gives a much cleaner argument. I've updated the answer, please let me know if anything is incorrect/missing.

Comment: @Rushy Thank you for your discussing. If it is ok, in the case of $R$ is valuation ring, I would be grateful you add in answer form.

Comment: @buoyant When $R$ is a valuation ring, this is II.4.3 in Hartshorne (or Stacks tag 01KD/01KZ); $f : \varepsilon \to \operatorname{Spec} R$ is separated and you have the diagram $$\begin{array}{ccc}
\operatorname{Spec} K & \rightarrow & \varepsilon \\
\downarrow & \nearrow & \downarrow \\
\operatorname{Spec} R & \rightarrow & \operatorname{Spec} R
\end{array},
$$ where the top arrow is any of the two maps $\operatorname{Spec} K \to \operatorname{Spec} R \xrightarrow{r / s} \varepsilon$. There is a unique arrow $\nearrow$ that fits in the diagram, and both $r$ and $s$ work, so $r = s$.

Comment: @Rushy  Could you tell me why $f$ is separated? And  I often see notation $ε(R)＝E(K)$, but is it not the same set ? ( I believe there are just bijection, not isom as a set).

Comment: @Rushy Is $ε$ affine scheme ?

Comment: It is indeed just a bijection, and $f$ is separated because that's part of the definition for  $\varepsilon$ to be a neron model for $E/K$ ($\varepsilon$ is a smooth, separated finite-type $R$-scheme).

Comment: @Russy In your answer, could you explain me more why composition of $SpecK→SpecR→ε$  are equal means $r$ and $s$ agree on the generic point of $SpecR$?

Comment: It's because the map $\operatorname{Spec} K \to \operatorname{Spec} R$ sends the point of $\operatorname{Spec} K$ to the generic point of $\operatorname{Spec} R$.

Comment: @Russy Thank you, I understood,  Could you tell me one more ? The definition of Neron model I know is that 'smooth group scheme over $SpecR$ whose generic fiber is $E/K$ and satisfies Neron mapping property'. From definition ,can I deduce that Neron model is separated scheme ? (How?)  And if you are ok, I want to ask  questions regrading arithmetic geometry, could you send me an email ?I'm moved by your answers. I'm undergraduate, I want to learn from you. If you are ok,  my email  address is otheiio323.com@gmail.com.

Comment: @Rushy To claim 'agree on generic point induces $r＝s$', I think I should say $ε$ is Hausdorff as topological space. But is that true ?

Comment: In the context of schemes, the 'correct' notion should be that $\varepsilon$ is seperated, i.e. the diagonal morphism is a closed immersion. Compare this with the definition of Hausdorfness (the diagonal is a closed subset).

Comment: @Rushy Could you tell me why two  SpecK→SpecR→ε (the last morphism is $r$ and $s$) map are equal ? You say this follows from definition of fiber product, but could you tell me more explanation about this ? Sorry to bother, but I'm looking for your reply.

Comment: If you draw the commutative diagram used to define the base changes $r_K : \operatorname{Spec} K \to \varepsilon_K$ and similarly $s_K$, you have that letting $\pi : \varepsilon_K \to \varepsilon$ be projection on the first factor $\pi \circ r_K = \pi \circ s_K$. Now looking in the diagram you can see $\pi \circ r_K = r \circ f$ where $f : \operatorname{Spec} K \to \operatorname{Spec} R$.

Comment: @Rushy To use valuation criterion of separateness, I need to check Neron model $ε$ is Noether scheme. How can I prove(check) this ?

Comment: @Alex Youcis : Why $ε$ is Noether scheme ? As I said to Rushy, to use valuation criterion of separateness, I need to check Neron model is Noether scheme.

Comment: @buoyant $\varepsilon$ is of finite type over a noetherian base ($R$ is noetherian), hence noetherian